# I can't retrieve relationships

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I have a Person node and a call relationship.I want to find a specific person and those who called him.My code are as below

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person extends BaseEntity{
     @Property(name = "id")
     private String mobile;
     private String name;
     private int partition;
     private int StronglyConnectedComponents;
     private int ConnectedComponent;
     private int LabelPropagation;
     private double pagerank;
     private int seed_label;   //在线算法结果写回字段
     @Relationship(type="Call",direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
     private List<Person> contact;
     //setter and getter
}
@RelationshipEntity(type = "Call")
public class Call extends BaseEntity{
   @StartNode
   private Person caller;
   @EndNode
   private Person callee;
   private String BS;
   private String time;
   //setter and getter
}
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person>{
    Person findById(String id, @Depth int depth);
}


public String test() {
    Person person = community.personRepository.findById("18565124452",2);
    return person.toString();
}
```

**Use test method I can retrieve the properties of the person node but the relationship property contact is null. How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an older Spring Data Neo4j version. But this shouldn't be a problem here. In your person class you are defining

```
 @Relationship(type="Call",direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
 private List<Person> contact;
```

where it should be

```
 @Relationship(type="Call",direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
 private List<Call> contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with null relationships. I think the only way to fetch relationships is by using cypher query language. Correct the mistake meistermeir point out. Try adding this method to your repository class.

```
   @Query("MATCH (p:Person) WHERE ID(p)=18565124452 MATCH (p)-[call:Call*]->(p2) return p, call, p2")
    Person getPersonById(long personId);
```

Also, I think you need to change :

```
 @Property(name = "id")
```

to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

in order to generate unique id's every time you create new Person nodes.